# Query EF Graph with method syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity graph I am returning from a data layer that I want to query on so the collection will display in gridview (my attempt to flatten the graph).  How can I do this with the method syntax?

I am interested in any better way or best practice in flattening entity graphs with collections.

```
// schedule is entity graph and days is a child collection in the graph
    var gridView = from s in schedule
                   from b in s.days
                   select new
                   {
                       id = s.Id,
                       custnum = s.CustNum,
                       days = b.Days
                   }
    dataGridView1 = gridView.ToList();
```

Comment: I consider query syntax best practice when it comes to `SelectMany` (which this is), because it's much much easier to comprehend.

Comment: @ Gert Arnold I understand, but I want to better understand both ways of doing it so figured I would ask for some feedback.